# Insert range of value based on SQL where clause count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012, say I have this:

```
select '12358', resource_code, 'N', '1' from sch_resource
where resource_desc like '%avid%media%comp%dongle'
```

instead of inserting '1', I want to instead insert 1 to X, where X is:

```
select count(resource_code) from sch_resource
where resource_desc like '%avid%media%comp%dongle'
```

Is there an easy way to do this without a loop?

Result, count equal to 7, would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it just simply be:

```
select '12358', resource_code, 'N', 
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY resource_code)
from dbo.sch_resource
where resource_desc like '%avid%media%comp%dongle'
ORDER BY rn;
```

If in your real code you're selecting more than one (whatever column 1 is), and you want the row numbering to start over with each new value in (whatever column 1 is), then you can say:

```
select [whatever column 1 is], resource_code, 'N', 
  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
       (PARTITION BY [whatever column 1 is] ORDER BY resource_code)
from dbo.sch_resource
where resource_desc like '%avid%media%comp%dongle'
ORDER BY [whatever column 1 is], rn;
```